# Registering a listener in a runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, service, runnable

I am trying to run the following code. T
he purpose of the code is to detect a call and to terminate it immediately. It consists of:

1) A main service class which contains the handler for communication with the new thread I use and a runnable which has the code to run. It also has fundamental implementation of other functions.

2)The other class extends the PhoneStateListener which is required for the listener.

I've tried individual components and joined them but I did it as part of an activity. They all work fine but now I am trying to do all that in the background through the use of a service running a separate thread. The application breaks when the service is started.

```
public class Call_Message_Service extends Service {

Thread serviceThread;
CallStateListener callStateListener;
//Handler to allow communication with main thread to display some toasts.
public Handler serviceHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        String string = bundle.getString("KEY");
        Toast.makeText(Call_Message_Service.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
//Main runnable
Runnable serviceRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "HERE_1");
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener(serviceHandler);
        //Register PhoneStateListener
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    serviceThread = new Thread (serviceRunnable);
    serviceThread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

String number;
Handler extraHandler;

public CallStateListener(Handler handler) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "HERE_2");
    extraHandler = handler;
}

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    //Store is number of the incoming call
    number = incomingNumber;

    //If phone is ringing
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
        Message msg = extraHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String string = "Phone is Ringing";
        bundle.putString("KEY",string);
        disconnectCallAndroid();
    }
    //If incoming call received
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
        Message msg = extraHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String string = "Phone is Currently in a call";
        bundle.putString("KEY",string);
    }
    //If not ringing or idle
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
        Message msg = extraHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String string = "Phone is neither Ringing nor in a call";
        bundle.putString("KEY",string);
    }
}

//Function to disconnect call
public int disconnectCallAndroid()
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int nResp = 0;
    try
    {
        Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "service call phone 5 \n");
        runtime.exec("service call phone 5 \n");
    }catch(Exception exc)
    {
        Log.e(Constants.LOGTAG, exc.getMessage());
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return nResp;
}
}
```

At least that is what the code should be doing. I think the problem lies in trying to register a listener from a runnable but I am pretty sure there are many more problems.
It would be great if someone could point out everything wrong with the code.

The main activity is very simple, just a button which when pressed starts the service. The service is started and the execution goes as far as the first Log but breaks after that with the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening:

The `serviceHandler` that you are passing to `CallStateListener` is being used inside a `Runnable` that is executed on a separate `Thread`.

When a `Handler` is used on a new `Thread`, it needs to be attached to the `Thread`'s `Looper`. The `Looper` is responsible for managing the `MessageQueue` of that particular `Thread`. If there is no `Looper` attached the `Handler` cannot process `Messages` (or `Runnables`).

You might ask, why don't I need to attach the main `Thread` to the `Looper`, then?

Android attaches the main `Thread` to its `Looper` for you when the `Application` starts. This interaction is managed by `ActivityThread`. If you look at the source of `ActivityThread` you will see there is a call to `Looper.prepareMainLooper();`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I dont quite understand all of it but i'll go over some tutorials to better understand loopers and handlers better. So what changes would I have to make to make it work ???